# How do I use yolk from within a python script to get the latest version for a specific package?

Tags: python, pip, pypi, yolk

I would like something like:

```
yolk.get_lastest_version_number(package_name)
```

which would return a version number.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that will return the latest version number of a package, or None if there is no such package.

```
from yolk.pypi import CheeseShop

def get_lastest_version_number(package_name):
    pkg, all_versions = CheeseShop().query_versions_pypi(package_name)
    if len(all_versions):
        return all_versions[0]
    return None

>>> get_lastest_version_number('requests')
'2.7.0'
>>> get_lastest_version_number('pip')
'6.1.1'
>>> get_lastest_version_number('django')
'1.8.1'
>>> get_lastest_version_number('Django')    # case insensitive
'1.8.1'
>>> print get_lastest_version_number('dunno')
None
```